# Can't undo a checkout

Tags: check-out

Am I correct in saying I cannot undo a checkout for a document in SharePoint 2013?

I can only discard check out.

Comment: What if i do not want to discard the changes but also want to exclude them for not being commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Discard checkout` - The changes that you made to the file since you checked it out are discarded.

For example, if you have checked-out a file and made some changes, but now you decide you dont want these changes. Then if you click on discard checkout, you will lose those changes. So, discard checkout = undo checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Discard check out will actually undo the changes that happened after the last check in, which is in fact an undo check out process.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. At least how it is written. If I check out a document, make changes, and then check it back in, I cannot select Discard Check Out.

Comment: Exactly, because the discard check out will discard the check out since the document was last checked in. If you check in the document, that's it, there's nothing to discard, as the name says, it discards the current check out.

Comment: So the changes that you have done after the last check in, will be discarded.